# I have account and pen object where pen is child of account. I need to query the pen record with latest created date for all account query on pen obj

Tags: apex, soql

I have tried the query with group by and im hitting error for malformed query

```
Select Count(id), name (select id,name from pens) from pen__c group by count(id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Pens__r ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Id in (SELECT Account__c FROM Pen__c WHERE Account__c !=null)
```

Comment: Hey Chris, this works perfectly. But only concern I'm facing and trying to adress is. It brings records of accounts which doesn't have data in pen records

Comment: Ho that's weird, because with the where clause "where Id in (select Account__c from Pen__c where Account__c!=null)" , it should not retrieve any account record that does not have a Pen record...

Comment: this is really strange I don't know what to say... can you paste some output of the query  where you have account records without Pen child record ?